# What does "1", "2", "3" mean in protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

```
package tutorial;

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

What does "1", "2", "3" mean ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Each field in the message definition has a unique numbered tag. These tags are used to identify your fields in the message binary format, and should not be changed once your message type is in use.

https://web.archive.org/web/20120321055631/http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html

Comment: Can't the field number be inferred from the declaration?

Comment: @WilderField With explicit numbering, you can sort and organize the fields in arbitrary order without affecting the generated code. That will be useful when refactoring.

Answer (score 8):

They're the field numbers - they're used in the wire representation to identify which field is associated with a value. This means that renaming a field isn't a breaking change (in terms of wire format) and the names themselves don't have to be serialized.